# Spring data xml configuration for mysql

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set up a project with Spring Data and MySql. I'm running into the following error while deploying the application with tomcat:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
```

I have configured a repository as follows:

```
<jpa:repository base-package="com.navin.logging.repositories" />
```

Here is the top of my xml config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
```

And here are my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think this was a result of conflicting versions of different dependencies. Upgrading to the latest versions of everything fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `…-commons-core` dependency is obsolete. Even better remove `spring-data-commons` as well. `spring-data-jpa` should pull in all the necessary dependencies anyway.

Minor tip: use the version-less XSD declarations in your XML config file (i.e. `spring-context.xsd` instead of `spring-context-3.0.xsd`). That will prevent conflicts occuring if the schema files include other version of the same schema file transitively.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. Using the version-less XSD seemed to fix it, but I've upgraded to the latest versions anyway.